# Wii U launch directly to Wii menu?

Tags: wii-u

The latest Wii U firmware lets you boot directly to Wii mode. You are supposed to hold B during the boot screen. When I do this it says "going to Wii menu", then fades out and shows a logo with "Wii U Menu", then the user selection screen.

Am I doing something wrong? Has anybody else gotten this to work? Ice tried holding for various lengths of time, and nothing seems to help...

Comment: The Wii U can do that?  I had no idea!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @fbueckert last system update added it

Comment: same happening for me, and sometimes the Wii controls doesn't work very well. I'm still trying to find out how to do it. Maybe I'll try with a Wiimote rather than the gamepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, but is tricky because the wiimote needs to connect to the Wii U too.

1. Turn on the Wii U.
2. As soon as the Wii U logo shows, Press and hold B on the wiimote.
3. If the lights on the wiimote stop blinking, Press and hold B again.
4. If done successfully, you will hear a chime.

This will bring you to the user selection menu, which will have a line stating

> (Wii menu will open.)

After you have selected your user, the Wii menu will open.

Comment: Holding B on the Wii Remote instead of the Wii U Control Pad totally worked the first time.  The timing is tricky, I grant you, but it's certainly better than adding a few minutes to the boot routine by trekking through the main Wii U menu.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does work, I'm not sure the exact timing of it. To be sure I just hold B the whole time the Wii U controller is showing the Wii U logo (you don't have to hold it earlier than this). There's probably some point in there where you can let go, but when doing that it boots directly into the Wii menu for me.

Comment: I wonder if something is wrong with my system?  I held B until it brought me to the User Select screen, which I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to do when booting to Wii mode.  Maybe the problem is that I have more than one user account on the Wii U.  Do you have more than one user?

Comment: @JamesB it might do that since you don't have a user set as default or whatever? I only have one user and it never takes me to the user screen.

Comment: I thought that, so I changed it to have a default user, and now it *only* takes me to the user screen when I hold B -- otherwise, it boots straight to the Wii U menu.  Maybe if I have a chance I'll delete all the users except my main one, then see if that fixes it.